# Jest not recognizing ECMAScript Modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, babeljs

I am getting an error when i run the test

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens when your code or its dependences use non-standaed javascript syntax.

```
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    > 2 | import axios from 'axios';
        | ^
      3 |
      4 | const useTreeDataFetching = (url) => {
      5 |   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/hooks/useTreeDataFetching.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/TreeList/TreeList.js:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/TreeList.test.js:3:1)
```

my package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "prettier": "3.0.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Jest, by default, doesn't understand ESM directives like `import` and expects CJS instead (`require()`). It does have an experimental mode to support import but that's not production ready - see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules if you want to try this.

The typical approach is to transform files so they use `require()` instead of `import` using babel-jest. If you do this, babel must be correctly configured to output CJS instead of ESM. There are various ways to do this, but the easiest way is to use

```
presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]],
```

Make sure that this config only applies when you run tests though, as this code may not work correctly in a browser.

You will also find that jest, by default, doesn't transform code in `node_modules` under the assumption that library modules will ship CJS - this is not always correct but you can account for this by tweaking `transformIgnorePatterns` - see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring for details.

Comment: after adding that also i have the same error

Comment: Where did you add it?

Comment: in the package.json file
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]
    ]
  },